# Issues with classes in C++

Tags: c++

I started taking a C++ course but I am stuck on the classes. I copied the code exactly and it does not seem to work. I've had this issue for 3 days now and I've tried a lot of things like switching compliers and creating new projects. If anyone knows what the issue is please help me.

It also is not giving me any errors. It just does not launch at all.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Person person;

    cout << person.toString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
//person.cpp
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person()
{
    name = "George";
}

string Person::toString()
{
    return "Person's name is " + name;
}
```

```
//person.h
#pragma once
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string name;
             

public:
    Person();
    string toString();
};


#endif // !1
```

Comment: You don't need the header guard if you're using #pragma once

Comment: Are u sure it doesnt launch. Or does it launch and quit right after ?

Comment: @J.Lengel `#pragma once` is not standard, but a common compiler extension. Not every compiler supports it.

Comment: Also, as far as I know the operator std::string + std::string is undefined so your toString function shouldn't even compile

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Even so, depending on the compiler you're using you should pick one, not use both. It's excessive

Comment: @J.Lengel No problem with `std::string + std::string`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) Also works if *either* operand is a `const char*`.

Comment: Wow I must be old. I was thinking of pre c++11 times :)

Comment: Just a guess, but have you included your `main.cpp` file in the build?

Comment: 1. Like people said, you don't need both `#pragma once` and include guards. 2. You should always assume the file system is case-sensitive, so if your header is named "person.hpp", you should use `#include "person.hpp"`, and not `#include "Person.hpp"`. 3. Your code should work (worked for me, at least).

Comment: This works for me. The problem is not in the code. @Adrian Mole has a good point. Maybe you should post your build and run commands.

Comment: "_I've tried a lot of things like switching compliers_" - You're on to something, but instead of swtiching: _verify_ using **all** compilers.

Comment: Before you learn 'how to program' you have to learn 'how to use your compiler' that seems to be the issue here, but unfortunately there's not really enough information to help

Comment: Is this the first program you have written with two .cpp files? That's often a stumbling block.

Comment: when you compile a hello world program, can you run it and see the output?

Comment: I strongly suggest running terminal programs from a terminal. Trying to run terminal programs from an IDE is more trouble than it's worth, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an issue on how you build it.

I'm running Linux, so this is what I've did:

Wrote the code to this files:

```
main.cpp  Person.cpp  Person.h
```

Compiled the code:

```
~/dev/cpp$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o app Person.cpp main.cpp 
~/dev/cpp$ ./app
```

This is the output:

```
Person's name is George
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running windows

I opened VS 2019 new project and added your files and it worked... I think you have a problem with how you open the project in your IDE (framework), try to see a tutorial about how to open the project in your IDE

this is tutorial to open a VS 2019 project:
https://youtu.be/jUrMD1zfGVc

good luck!